# When a property is changed several times very quickly, how many PropertyChanged events are sent?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I have some code that implements a PropertyChanged event (similar to the snippet below).

```
private void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         if(PropertyChanged != null)
         {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
         }
      }
```

I noticed that my event handler is only called once, when the same property is changed several times very quickly.  I can't find any documentation that mentions this.  Can anyone confirm if this is the expected behaviour for PropertyChanged?

Comment: How do you know it is only called once? Maybe the way you are changing the property is actually changing the private member instead and only one place sets the property?

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers.  It was a stupid bug, to do with calling SendPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a C# event is actually not much more than a function call.  There are 2 main differences from a regular function call: -

1. With events, the callee has a dependency on the caller, rather than the other way around.
2. The event can have an invocation list, that is, multiple callees can be attached to a single caller.

There is no throttling built into the event raising mechanism, so the effect you're seeing must have a different explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The code you show will invoke the event's delegate as many times as `SendPropertyChanged` is invoked. There is no magic here. However, one common approach (back a level in the code you don't show) is to check for actual changes, for example:

```
private int id;
public int Id {
    get { return id; }
    set {
        if(id != value) {
            id = value;
            SendPropertyChanged(); // let C# 5 compiler tricks supply the name
        }
    }
}
private void SendPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
    }
}
```

With test:

```
    var obj = new Foo();
    int count = 0;
    obj.PropertyChanged += delegate { count++; };

    obj.Id = 1;
    obj.Id = 2;
    obj.Id = 3;

    Console.WriteLine(count); // outputs: 3

    count = 0;
    obj.Id = 1;
    obj.Id = 1;
    obj.Id = 1;

    Console.WriteLine(count); // outputs: 1
```